# Traceroute : why my packets travel around the world?

Tags: networking, traceroute

I'm actually in Vietnam, and when I run traceroute to check path between me and my server in France, my packets seem to like travel all around the world, instead of going straight to France.

Here is the path :

- local router
- Saigon (Vietnam)
- Hong Kong
- Tokyo
- Palo Alto
- San Jose
- Miami
- Belgium
- France

So it's a 30,000 km trip! I think it could be around 10,000km by choosing the west side.
Why the Internet likes the long way ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the "long way" is the faster way.

The path is decided based by the [routing protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_protocol). In a simplistic view, each hop is planned according the number of `hops` needed to reach the destination ([RIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol) works this way).

In real world, probably more information is used, for example speed of the each path and manual tunning.

Answer (score 0):

It's a packet switched network. The sender has no influence over (and shouldn't care about) the route the packets take to the destination, as long as they get there. Why are you even worried about this?

Comment: If one link has huge packet loss, it is of some consequence.